# JavaFX 2.0 + FXML. Updating scene values from a different Task

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

I want to get the controller from a scene that i've loaded with FXMLoader. The use case is:

1. My JSON manager receives a JSON object
2. The task I've launched shows a new Scene using

   ```
   Parent p = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("foo.fxml"));
   Scene scene = new Scene(p);
   stage.setScene(scene);
   ```

   After that, i have the empty scene.
3. Now I do this to fill the components

   ```
   AnchorPane pane = (AnchorPane)((AnchorPane) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().get(0);
   for(Node node : pane.getChildren()){
       String id = node.getId();
       if(id.equals(NAME)){
            ((TextField)node).setText(value);
       }
   }
   ```

My question, is there an easier way to do this? I have a controller specified in FXML

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="526.0" minWidth="356.0" prefHeight="526.0" prefWidth="356.0" 
xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="bar.foo">
```

I want to get the instance with the bind values (TextField called name in this case)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1) You can get the controller from the `FXMLLoader` but don't know is it possible from `Scene` :

```
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
Pane p = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("foo.fxml").openStream());
bar.foo fooController = (bar.foo) fxmlLoader.getController();
```

To use the `fooController` later in a different part of your code, you can use `Node#setUserData()`. For example after the code above:

```
p.setUserData(fooController);
...
// after a while of app logic and code
bar.foo controller_of_p = (bar.foo) p.getUserData();
```

This gives a workaround and a shortcut to achieve your goal.

2) If your node has an id then you can directly `Node#lookup()` it rather than constructing a for-loop :

```
TextField txt = (TextField) pane.lookup("#nodeId");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was a point using node.lookup. The way you show to get the controller doesn't works for me because I need the current controller instance. This way creates a new controller and a new pane.

Comment: why? Use this code instead of `FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("foo.fxml"));` and you will get the same pane as in your code.

Comment: @Javier. Updated the answer. Please have a look.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for Uluk Bly, thanks!. @Sergey: If you use loader.getResource(...) different times, each time the controller instance will be different.

Comment: @Javier, i've looked into history and nobody suggested doing that. But nvm as you got your problem solved. :)