# How can I access a Controller class in JavaFx 2.0?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, controller, javafx-2

Recently I was programming a software with JavaFx2.0,but I met with a big problem,that is - How can I access a Controller class?
For every controller class with the same class type,they may act different because of the model it depends on,so I want to get
the view's Controller class and provide it with the specified model,can I do this?
I have tried to get the controller by the FXMLLoader,but the method getController() returns null!why?

1.LightView.java

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
anchorPane = loader.load(LightView.class.getResource(fxmlFile));//fxmlFile = "LightView.fxml"
//controller = (LightViewController) loader.getController();//fail to get controller!it is null
//I want to -> controller.setLight(light);
```

2.LightView.fxml

```
<AnchorPane ... fx:controller="light.LightViewController" >
```

3.LightViewController.java

```
....
private Light light;
public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1)
```

4.Light.java

```
.... a simple pojo
```

so,what I want to do is provide every LightViewController with a specified Light Object(they are from a List).
Can anyone helps me?Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe this answer could be helpful: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/10108788/682495](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10108788/682495).

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFX 2.0 + FXML. Updating scene values from a different Task](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107829/javafx-2-0-fxml-updating-scene-values-from-a-different-task)

Answer (score 49):

I use the following :

```java
URL location = getClass().getResource("MyController.fxml");

FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());

Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());
```

In this way `fxmlLoader.getController()` is not `null`

Comment: Thank you very much!Your method is quite what I need!Thank you angain!

Comment: I have a situation where `fxmlLoader.getController()` didn't work that way. But I don't know why!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Alf's answer, I want to note, that the code can be shorter:

```
URL location = getClass().getResource("MyController.fxml");

FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();

Parent root = (Parent) fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());
```

This works as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResourceAsStream` instead :

```java
anchorPane = loader.load(LightView.class.getResourceAsStream(fxmlFile));
```

Its simple, work well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("LightView.fxml"));
    loader.load();
    Parent parent = loader.getRoot();
    Scene Scene = new Scene(parent);
    Stage Stage = new Stage();
    LightViewController lv = loader.getController();
    lv.setLight(light);
    Stage.setScene(Scene);
    Stage.show();
```