# How to connect Java back-end with JavaFX 2 front-end?

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have a Java-code business logic and a JavaFX2-code GUI.
A Java `Game.java` class interacts with a `GameGUI.java` FX class via an EventBroker and listeners.
The main classes are in the back-end package `Main.java` and in the front-end package `MainGUI.java`, so the application is started from the *start*-method in the `MainGUI` class.

How can I connect the back-end (Main) with the front-end (MainGUI)? Is there a method to set the Java back-end classes as model for the GUI? I'm just getting started with JavaFX...

Comment: `MainGUI` is a regular java class that extends `javafx.application.Application`. You can use the Main.java and its methods in it. What do you mean by "connect" more specifically?

Comment: Are the JavaFX GUI and the Backend executed on the same machine?

Comment: Would you know how to do it in Swing or AWT? If you do, you can think along the same lines and exchange the names. (You'll miss out on some points, though, but you can remedy that once you learn.)

Comment: @UlukBiy: So should I just instantiate the Main.java class in the start method of MainGUI.java and that's it?

Comment: @Arian: Yes, they are executed on the same machine.

Comment: @UrsReupke: Not in Swing or AWT, just Java and JavaFX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainGUI` is a regular java class that extends `javafx.application.Application`. You can instantiate the `Main` class and use its methods in it.

Furthermore, to understand the MVC-like pattern of JavaFX refer to these links:
[Mastering FXML](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/why_use_fxml.htm) part "Introduction to FXML".
[MVC Pattern in JavaFX With Scene Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10872444/682495).

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a GUI library, not an application framework, there is no model/view concept in JavaFX.

You'll have to connect your classes manually.

Comment: OK, and how do I connect them manually? Sorry, I'm still a student and no Java expert ;)

Comment: No problem. Reading the comments above, you found it out by yourself by now.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways:
1) Front end will spawn a thread to backend
2) You can manually create a method object which can access