# JavaFX Scene Builder - How can I access the components

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx, scenebuilder

I've build a Gui using the scene builder application. I've loaded it into my application but I want to add components to a VBox buried in the design. It seems that all i have access to use is the AnchorPanel that is returned from FXMLLoader.load.

Is there any way more elegant then drilling down the children tree's to get to the component i want?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to add to the VBox from some random class:

1. give an `fx:id` to the VBox, say `"vbox"`
2. create a Controller for the view and associate it to the view in the FXML
3. in the Controller, add a `@FXML VBox vbox;` (where `vbox` it the same as the `fx:id`)
4. [retrieve the controller from the FXMLLoader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10753277/829571) and access the VBox: `controller.vbox;`.

If you just need to add something to the VBox when your view is loaded, follow 1 to 3 above and add the relevant code in the initialize method of the Controller.

Comment: Your link showed me where i went wrong. I was using the static load(URL) instead of the FXMLLoader load(Stream). Thanks!