# fxml getController() returns null

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am newbie in JavaFX. Can anyone help me?

Here is my code

```
Stage stage = new Stage();

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml").openStream());
FXMLMainController mainController = loader.getController();
mainController.setStage(stage);
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.show();

((Node) (event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
```

loader.getController() returns null

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at library.management.system.FXMLDocumentController.loginButtonAction(FXMLDocumentController.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1763)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1651)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8175)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:204)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3746)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3471)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1695)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2486)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:314)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:243)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:345)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:526)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:898)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: where you have the FXMLMain.fxml file? is it in same directory where the java class resides?

Comment: try this too... Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml").toExternalForm());

Comment: Also take a look at this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461148/fxmlloader-getcontroller-returns-null

Comment: Most probably, your `Button` is not initialised in the controller !

Comment: @Jayaprasad
Of course my FXMLMain.fxml is in the same directory where I have the java class.

I also tried
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml").toExternalForm());
but it shows me an error
"no suitable method found for load(String)"

Comment: @ItachiUchiha
My button is initialized in the controller

Comment: @James_D
this is line 69
mainController.setStage(stage);

Comment: Do you have an `fx:controller` attribute set in your FXML?

Answer (score 12):

This not work

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.load(url);
FXMLController controller = loader.getController(); // return null
```

This work

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
FXMLController controller = loader.getController(); // return the controller
```

Comment: This answer probably saved me hours of brooding and self doubt. Is this a bug, bad design, or is there actually a good reason for it?

Answer (score 4):

add the `fx:controller` attribute to the root item and give the controller java file name.
for example: if your root item is `AnchorPane` and `FXMLMainController` the controller java file then

```
<AnchorPane fx:controller:"FXMLMainController">
</AnchorPane>
```

the root item in the `FXMLMain.fxml` add `fx:controller="/folder/controllerjavafilename"`

Note: I assume that your fxml and controller file are the same place.

Answer (score 1):

I know my answer is late, but I will put to benefit anyone who will fall on this page after.

short answer:

change this:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent root = (Parent) loader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml").openStream());
FXMLMainController mainController = loader.getController();
```

to that:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("FXMLMain.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
FXMLMainController mainController = loader.getController();
```

Explaination:

The problem is that you are invoking the load() method (which is a static method) using an instance variable instead of the FXMLLoader class.
It is understandable that you need to use the instance so that you can invoke the getController() method. In this case, You should pass the URL (using getClass().getResource()) to the constructor of the FXMLLoader while you are creating your instance, then you can get the Parent root just by using the load() method.
Your order of method calls is correct so just as a reminder for other, remember that you need to call the load() method first before getController() or else it will return null

I ran into this problem before and this is how I solved it.

Answer (score -1):

this works

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(Main.class.getResource(xmlNm+".fxml"));
Parent rootLayout = loader.load();
FXMLController controller = loader.getController();
```

Comment: Can you explain why your code works relative to the question being asked?