# fxmlLoader.getControler return null

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, fxmlloader

I'm a beginner with javafx and I'm trying for the first time to use the builder scene. I built my scene and I can display it without any problem. I applied the instructions of this post to interact with the fxml file:[Accessing FXML controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class)

Here is my code :

```
public class View extends Application {
static MyController myControllerHandle;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/resources/foo.fxml"));
    Parent p = fxmlLoader.load();
    MyController fooController = fxmlLoader.getController();
    Scene scene = new Scene(p);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Application.launch(View.class,args);
}}
```

The scene is displayed but the controller is null. I found some posts about it but none of them solved my problem.

Post about it :

- [FXMLLoader getController returns NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461148/fxmlloader-getcontroller-returns-null)
- [fxml getController() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24429809/fxml-getcontroller-returns-null/24597719)

It's probably a stupid mistake but I've been stuck on it for a long time...
Thank you in advance

EDIT :

For the beginner here is the solution: Add the controller class in the fxml file.

Comment: You don't give your FXML file. Do you have the `fx:controller` attribute defined in you FXML file?

Comment: Yes indeed it was my mistake! Thank you so much!