# JavaFX - Passing int values between controller classes yielding incorrect result

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a little quiz game I'm making, however when I try to pass a value from one of my controllers to another, the answer is always the opposite of what I expect. Basically, a radio button is selected, and if the correct one is selected, the `returnValue()` method should return a 1, else 0. This tells me if the user selected the proper answer or not.

Code for controller 1:

```
public class Question1
{
    @FXML
    private Label question1Lbl;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rb1;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rb2;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton rb3;

    private static int score;

    public void nextQuestion(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {
        try
        {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../gui/Question2.fxml"));
            Parent rootPane = loader.load();
            Stage primaryStage = new Stage();
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootPane));
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);
            primaryStage.setTitle("Frage 2");
            primaryStage.show();
            rb1.getScene().getWindow().hide();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error loading question 1" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    //returns the points for this question. 1 for correct, 0 for incorrect
    public int returnValue()
    {

        if (!rb2.isSelected())
        {
            score = 0;
            return score;
        }
        score = 1;
        return score;
    }
}
```

The `FinishScreen` class is supposed to tally up the points gathered from all the `returnValue()` methods and display a score, but no matter what I try, the `Question1` class always returns 0, whether the radio button was selected or not! I've written code like this before and it's worked fine, so I'm confused. I have 4 more classes like this, too.

Anyway, here is the `FinishScreen` class:

```
public class FinishScreen implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private Label resultLbl;

    private int totalScore;

    public void calculateScore() throws Exception
    {
        FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("../gui/Question1.fxml"));
        Parent root1 = loader1.load();
        Question1 q1 = loader1.getController();

        totalScore = q1.returnValue();
        System.out.println(totalScore);
        resultLbl.setText("Score: " + totalScore);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        try
        {
            calculateScore();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in results " + e.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

I used info from this post as a reference for how to pass values from one controller to another:
[FXMLLoader getController returns NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461148/fxmlloader-getcontroller-returns-null)

If there is an error in the way I am trying to get the value from my `Question1` class that would make sense, but most other posts I've read seem to follow this design pattern as well. It is a silly problem to have, yet I cannot figure it out.

My `returnValue()` should return a 1 when `rb2.isSelected() == true` but that isn't the case. I tried making the `score` member variable static as well and that hasn't helped. What could be the issue here?

Comment: don't use static fields, ever! They have class scope - that is in your case, every newly loaded Question modifies the exact same field which is bound to lead to unpredicable results. For passing parameters around controllers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use a `static` field to store the results, those results are are retrieved from the controls in the scene when you call the `returnValue` method.

Loading the fxml a second time the way you do it in the `calculateScore` methods creates ***a new version of the scene*** though. In this new version of the scene the controls are in their initial states regardless of the user input done in the other version of the scene.

I recommend redesigning the app a bit:

- Seperate the logic for the question from the logic for "navigating" the questions.
- Keep a reference of the controller for later evaluation.
- You can make your life easier by implementing an interface with your controllers.

**Example**

```
private int questionIndex = -1;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    StackPane questionContainer = new StackPane();
    questionContainer.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    questionContainer.setPrefSize(300, 300);

    // create question list repeating our only question
    List<URL> questions = new ArrayList<>();
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/my/package/question1.fxml");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        questions.add(url);
    }

    List<QuestionController> questionControllers = new ArrayList<>(questions.size());

    Button next = new Button("next");
    EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler = evt -> {
        if (questionIndex + 1 < questions.size()) {
            questionIndex++;

            // load next question & store controller for later evaluation
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(questions.get(questionIndex));
            try {
                questionContainer.getChildren().setAll(loader.<Node>load());
                questionControllers.add(loader.getController());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        } else {
            // display results
            Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setContentText("You've answered "
                + questionControllers.stream().mapToInt(QuestionController::getScore).sum()
                + " / " + questionControllers.size()
                + " questions correctly.");
            alert.showAndWait();
            primaryStage.close();
        }
    };
    next.setOnAction(handler);

    // activate first question
    handler.handle(null);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(questionContainer, next)));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

```
public interface QuestionController {
    int getScore();
}
```

```
public class Question1Controller implements QuestionController {

    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private int correctAnswer;

    @FXML
    private List<RadioButton> buttons;

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {

        // randomly assign correct answer
        correctAnswer = random.nextInt(buttons.size());

        for (RadioButton btn : buttons) {
            btn.setText("incorrect");
        }

        buttons.get(correctAnswer).setText("correct");
    }

    @Override
    public int getScore() {
        return buttons.get(correctAnswer).isSelected() ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.util.ArrayList?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton?>

<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="my.package.Question1Controller">
    <children>
        <RadioButton fx:id="b1" />
        <RadioButton fx:id="b2" />
        <RadioButton fx:id="b3" />
        <fx:define>
            <ArrayList fx:id="buttons">
                <fx:reference source="b1"/>
                <fx:reference source="b2"/>
                <fx:reference source="b3"/>
            </ArrayList>
        </fx:define>
    </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Thank you, your input makes a lot of sense. I'm going to try this implementation later today and see how it works. If needed may I ask you additional questions about this? I will accept your answer once I try it regardless.

Comment: @FuegoJohnson As long as you simply need clarification regarding the answer or something is unclear, you can comment here. I may answer you in a comment or improve the answer...