# JavaFX: Set textfield value before showing window

Tags: javafx, textfield, setvalue

I'm creating a new modal dialog from the main controller class. How do I set some textfield values in the dialog before it is displayed?

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("SeedNodeForm.fxml");
Stage stage = new Stage();
stage.setTitle("Seed Node Information");
stage.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
stage.initOwner(((Node) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
stage.centerOnScreen();
```

*textfield1.setValue("foo!");

 textfield2.setValue("foo2");*

```
stage.showAndWait();
```

Comment: where do you want these textfields to be displayed ?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10753277).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Uluk Biy - your link led me to the answer which is:

```
// get the controller from the loader
SeedNodeFormController c = (SeedNodeFormController) fxmlLoader.getController();

// call setter in controller routine to set needed values
c.setSeedNode(value);
```