# javafx.scene.layout.Pane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader

Tags: java, javafx

I'm having trouble when trying to switch from a scene to another scene. The scenario is this:

**Current View and Controller**: `login.fxml` and `LoginController`

**Next step View and Controller**: `loggedWindow.fxml` and `UserPanelController`.

---

Now, I'm in `LoginController` and trying to switch the scene to `loggedWindow.fxml` sending to `UserPanelController` a parameter, but when I'm using my code I get:

```
javafx.scene.layout.Pane cannot be cast to javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
```

### LoginController:

```
FXMLLoader loggedWindow = null;
loggedWindow = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("loggedWindow.fxml")); // here crashes!
Pane root = loggedWindow.load();

UserPanelController controller = loggedWindow.getController();
controller.initData(customer);

Stage switchScene = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
switchScene.setResizable(false);
switchScene.setTitle("Welcome " + customer.FirstName + " " + customer.LastName);
switchScene.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 500));

switchScene.show();
```

### LoggedWindow.fxml

```
<Pane maxHeight="500.0" maxWidth="800.0" minHeight="500.0" minWidth="800.0" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Main.UserPanelController">
   <children>
      <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="831.0">
        <items>
         .
         .
         stuff (buttons/labels and so on).
         .
         .
</Pane>
```

I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.

### Update 1

Also took in consideration this reference: [Accessing FXML controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class)

Comment: Create first an instance: `FXMLLoader loggedWindow = new FXMLLoader(getClass()...);`, and then you can load the fxml file `Pane root = loggedWindow.load();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the "load" method of FXMLLoader which returns the root node of your .fxml file. In that case, it's returning your Pane.

You should use it to create your scene!

See the example given in the JavaFX tutorial, like:

```
Pane root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("loggedWindow.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene(root, width, height, color);
```

Other way, taken from one of my old code, using non-static FXMLLoader:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlFile));
Parent root;

try {
    root = loader.load();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // log exception
    return;
}

// Color.TRANSPARENT allows use of rgba colors (alpha layer)
setScene(new Scene(root, Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Comment: Well sounds interesting. But, I wonder if I can use `getController()` method inside of type `Pane`, because I tried and doesn't work.. :-?

Comment: If you want the controller,you need to call getController() of an FXMLLoader instance. In that case, loader.getController() if we look at my second example.