# How to let one controller properly call a second controllers method to update the second controlers fxml/node?

Tags: java, javafx, view, controller, label

So I have a root `BorderPane`, an `AnchroPane` for the left part and another `AnchorPane` for the bottom. Left contains a Button and Bottom contains a Label. All I want to achieve is that the `buttonClick()` method of LeftController updates the Bottom.fxml and displays a new text on the label.

I have read a couple of posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class), but nothing lead me to really solve all problems out.

This is a dummy project, which represents my bigger project (which I want to refactor to achieve better MVC structure) with which I finally want to get to understand how to communicate between controllers, which seems to be impossible for me right now.

My first approach was to make a new instance of the `BottomController` within `leftController`'s `initialize()`. That would let me access the `BottomController`'s `setLabelText()` method, but did not update the labels text. Eventough the console put showed me that the method was called, the labels text was not touched.

```
FXMLLoader loaderBottom = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("Bottom.fxml"));
bottom = loaderBottom.load();
bottomController = loaderBottom.getController();
```

My current approach (on my little dummyProject) to get those controllers to call methods of other controllers is by initializing them within the `Main`'s `start()` method and add a getter for each controller.
Then on the controller side I call those getters to make the controller accessible .. which unfortunately ends in some `InvocationTargetException`.

Is there a best practice approach update the other FXML's views from different controller classes?

This is the code of my current approach:

Main.java

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage rootStage;
    private BorderPane mainWindow;
    private AnchorPane left;
    private AnchorPane bottom;
    private MainWindowController mainWindowController;
    private LeftController leftController;
    private BottomController bottomController;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        this.rootStage = primaryStage;

        FXMLLoader loaderMainWindow = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("MainWindow.fxml"));
        mainWindow = loaderMainWindow.load();
        mainWindowController = loaderMainWindow.getController();
        // To make the connection from the controller class to the main class
        mainWindowController.setMain(this);

        FXMLLoader loaderBottom = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Bottom.fxml"));
        bottom = loaderBottom.load();
        bottomController = loaderBottom.getController();
        // To make the connection from the controller class to the main class
        bottomController.setMain(this);

        FXMLLoader loaderLeft = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("Left.fxml"));
        left = loaderLeft.load();
        leftController = loaderLeft.getController();
        // To make the connection from the controller class to the main class
        leftController.setMain(this);

        mainWindow.setLeft(left);
        mainWindow.setBottom(bottom);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainWindow);
        rootStage.setScene(scene);
        rootStage.show();
    }

    public MainWindowController getMainWindowController() { return mainWindowController;}
    public LeftController getLeftController() {return leftController;}
    public BottomController getBottomController() {return bottomController;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

LeftController.java

```
public class LeftController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button button;
    private Main main;
    private BottomController bottomController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        bottomController = main.getBottomController();
    }

    @FXML
    public void buttonClick(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Some Stuff..");
        bottomController.setLabelText("Some Stuff..");
    }

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
}
```

BottomController.java

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class BottomController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    private Main main;
    private LeftController leftController;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

    }

    @FXML
    public void setLabelText(String text) {
        label.setText(text);
    }

    public void setMain(Main main) {
        this.main = main;
    }
}
```

Left.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="100.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.LeftController">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="button" layoutX="237.0" layoutY="169.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#buttonClick" text="Button" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Bottom.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.BottomController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="label" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="203.0" layoutY="304.0" prefHeight="30.0" text="Label" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Exception:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Ruphus/IdeaProjects/controllerAccess/out/production/controllerAccess/sample/Left.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:39)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sample.LeftController.initialize(LeftController.java:22)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application sample.Main
```

So I would expect the following order of steps:
First: the `Main`'s `start()` method is called (besides `main()`). 
Second: `start()` calls the `setMain()` methods and by that makes the Main class accessable to the controllers
Third: The `LeftController`'s initialize is called to retreive a reference of `BottomController` to have it available.
Fourth: I click the button and change the labels text.

I am very confused by the error trace, since it navigates me to `left = loaderLeft.load();` within `main`. If I comment the line to retreive the BottomController within LeftController out, I can start with no error. So I must assume the controllers `initialize()` methods are called before the `start()` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @M.leRutte I don't thinkn so, since I am encountering a `InvocationTargetException`

Comment: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`--> `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException` --> `Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException` --> `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: ah  oups :D But thats not helping me. I pretty much understand what a NPE is but I can not see the problem with my code.

Comment: I guess `initialize` is called _before_ `setMain`?

Comment: @M.leRutte yeah I guess so too, but I don't know how to circumvent that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was so easy. Today I realized, that I just could move the `bottomController = main.getBottomController();` part into the `buttonClick()` method:

```
    @FXML
    public void buttonClick(javafx.event.ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        bottomController = main.getBottomController();
        System.out.println("Some Stuff..");
        bottomController.setLabelText("Some Stuff..");
    }
```

Now it finally interacts with the label as intended.