# JavaFx: how to reference main Controller class instance from CustomComponentController class?

Tags: reference, controller, javafx, instance, custom-component

WHAT I HAVE is a standard JavaFX application: `Main.java, MainController.java & main.fxml`. To add custom component, I created `CustomComponentController.java` and `custom_component_controller.fxml`.

PROBLEM is that in `CustomComponentController` methods I need to reference other methods and standard components from `MenuController`. I add `public static MainController mc;` to `MainController` class body, so that it can be seen from `CustomComponentController` (`MainController.mc.neededMethod()`). Then I try to pass everything to it in `MainController.initialize()` method (`mc = this;`) - when debugging this breakpoint, I see `this` full of components instances, but `mc` remains with null components afterwards.

QUESTION is how to reference the running instance of `MainController` to use its components and methods in other classes and to crossreference different custom components from each other? How to clean `MainController` code from event handlers and assistance methods of components by moving it all to component's own class?

I tried the following approaches, but found no way to make them work without errors:

[Accessing FXML controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751271/accessing-fxml-controller-class)

[How can I access a Controller class in JavaFx 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240471/how-can-i-access-a-controller-class-in-javafx-2-0)

[JavaFX 2.0 + FXML. Updating scene values from a different Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107829/javafx-2-0-fxml-updating-scene-values-from-a-different-task/10108788#10108788)

[JavaFX 2.2 -fx:include - how to access parent controller from child controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15004365/javafx-2-2-fxinclude-how-to-access-parent-controller-from-child-controller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved if you comply the following conditions:

1. Not only public, but obligatory static `MainController mc` should be.
2. Do not forget id in fxml for CustomComponentController: `<CustomComponentController fx:id="cc"/>`, where cc is the name of the "@FXML imported" CustomComponentController in your MainController class.
3. Omit parameter `fx:controller="main.CustomComponentController"` in `custom_component_controller.fxml` as it results in "Controller value already specified" error (a conflict between `main.fxml` and `custom_component_controller.fxml` markup declared controllers).
4. Put `mc = this;` in the beginning of `MainController`'s `initialize()` method. Before using `mc` in CustomComponentController class, check if it's not null. It can be null when all components, including `CustomComponentController`, are instantiated at application startup, but there is no mc instance yet. MainController method `initialize()` where MainController is instantiated is called after components are loaded. Therefore better practice is to use approach in the next paragraph.
5. In `main.fxml` create primary component of the same type that `CustomComponentController` and with the only `fx:id` parameter. Replace primary component with your `CustomComponentController` by creating `reloadCustomComponents()` method and calling it from `CustomComponentController`'s `initialize()` method. Do it by adding the following to `reloadCustomComponents()` method:

   customComponentAnchorPane.getChildren().remove(customComponent);

   customComponent = new customComponent();

   customComponentAnchorPane.getChildren().add(customComponent);

Thus all components can be placed outside `CustomComponentController` with all their methods and reloaded at the startup of the apllication. All component declarations stay in `MainController` class and can be reached through `MainController mc` reference. No duplicate creating of components in detail with parameters is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks like the classic catalog-crud forms updating, I implemented an interface that I called `Updatable` with an `update method` so I could reference any catalog form with any crud form easy after passing `Controller Main Class` as the `UserData Property` of the Child Root Component's Form

Hope it Can Solve your problem