# Accessing controls of a controller from another controller in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am building an simple javafx application using afterburner. I have main window which have a border pane and it's upper part contains menus and in center it have a vertical split pane which have two anchor panes with `fx:id=inputPane` and `fx:id=tablePane`. Now in `inputPane` i am loading different scenes and submitting data from it into `tablePane`.

Now i have a scene opened in `inputPane` which have a button and i want to submit the data from this scene into table as well as i want to open an another scene into `inputPane` and again want to submit it's data into table.

adara.fxml

```
<BorderPane fx:id="mainPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"  minHeight="180.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="507.0" prefWidth="800.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.qaf.presentation.adara.AdaraPresenter">
<top>
  <Pane prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
     <children>
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="800.0">
           <menus>
              <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Stock">
                 <items>
                    <MenuItem fx:id="createStock" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showCreateStockForm" text="Create" />
                    <MenuItem fx:id="incoming" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showIncomingForm" text="Incoming" />
                 </items>
              </Menu>
           </menus>
        </MenuBar>
     </children>
  </Pane>
</top>
 <center>
  <SplitPane dividerPositions="0.5" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="469.0" prefWidth="800.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
    <items>
        <BorderPane fx:id="contentBorderPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
           <center>
              <AnchorPane fx:id="contentBox" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
           </center>
        </BorderPane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="tableBox" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
    </items>
  </SplitPane>
</center>
</BorderPane>
```

adaraView.java

```
public class AdaraView extends FXMLView {

}
```

adaraPresenter.java

```
public class AdaraPresenter implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    AnchorPane contentBox;
    @FXML
    AnchorPane tableBox;


    StockCreationPresenter stockCreationPresenter;
    InwardsPresenter inwardsPresenter;
    ViewStockPresenter viewStockPresenter;



    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {       
        StockCreationView scView = new StockCreationView();  

        // other codes     
        .
        .


        ViewStockView vsView = new ViewStockView();

        // other codes     
        .
        .

        contentBox.getChildren().add(scView.getView());
        tableBox.getChildren().add(vsView.getView());
    }

    public void showCreateStockForm(){
        StockCreationView scView = new StockCreationView();

        // other codes     
        .
        .
        ViewStockView vsView = new ViewStockView();

        // other codes     
        .
        .

        contentBox.getChildren().add(scView.getView());
        tableBox.getChildren().add(vsView.getView());
    }
    public void showIncomingForm(){
        InwardsView inView = new InwardsView();

        // other codes     
        .
        .

        ViewStockView vsView = new ViewStockView();

        // other codes     
        .
        .

        contentBox.getChildren().add(inView.getView());
        tableBox.getChildren().add(vsView.getView());
    }
}
```

Here is the main class which is starting the stage and application.

Main.java

```
public class App extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {        
        AdaraView appView = new AdaraView();       
        Scene scene = new Scene(appView.getView());    
        stage.setTitle("Adara");
        final String uri = getClass().getResource("app.css").toExternalForm();        
        scene.getStylesheets().add(uri);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {        
        Injector.forgetAll();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Now here is the `InwardsPresenter.java` which have to save the `stockCreationPresenter.java` data into table as well as it have to open the inwardsView into the `contentPane`.

InwardsPresenter.java

```
public class InwardsPresenter implements Initializable {
    @FXML
    Button saveButton;
    @FXML 
    TextField orderNo;
    @FXML 
    TextField other;
    @FXML
    CheckBox save;

    @Inject
    AdaraPresenter adaraPresenter;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    }


    public void save() {

        Inwards inward = newInward();

        inward.setOrderNo(Integer.parseInt(orderNo.getText()));
        inward.setOther(other.getText());
        inward.setSave(save.isSelected());

        this.newInward.set(inward);

        adaraPresenter.incomingForm();
    }
}
```

// while executing `adaraPresenter.incomingForm();` it's showing NPE to contentBox and tableBox.

```
                 Thank you very much for any help.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaFx: how to reference main Controller class instance from CustomComponentController class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17550578/javafx-how-to-reference-main-controller-class-instance-from-customcomponentcont)

Comment: I got through that link @NwDx it's not the same, i got access to the controller but not to the UI component. I want to access UI component of one presenter from another presenter..

Comment: I think you have a reference to a different presenter instance than the one that was generated by loading the FXML file. But there is a fundamental problem with what you're trying to do here. Afterburner is an implementation of the Model-View-Presenter pattern. Accessing components belonging to one view from the presenter for another view basically violates that pattern. You need these to interact via some shared model.

Comment: Thank you very much @James_D for pointing out that fundamental problem but how can i achieve my requirement ? By  interacting via shared model do you mean creating a viewModel and use it wherever i need it, or using some property binding and listeners ? I tried both these methods but it's not helping me. Thanks again.

Comment: The "proper" way would be to create a view model, inject it into the presenters that need access to it, and bind/observe properties in it. But note on your `FXMLView` subclasses, you can also call `getPresenter()` to get a reference to the presenter; e.g. in your `showIncomingForm` method, you can do `InwardsView inView = new InwardsView();` `InwardsPresenter inPresenter = (InwardsPresenter)inView.getPresenter();` which means you can then communicate between the two presenters.

Comment: I already tested  injecting `viewModel`  @James_D and i know how to communicate using `getPresenter()`. My concern is very simple, if i have to replace a scene on a button click event to the same area (pane) where  event is taking place then how would i do that without accessing that area (pane) while the scene i am replacing have a different presenter than one i am replacing with.

Comment: Somebody please help me with this..